# Name of QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

What is the name of this QGIS Plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's called "Raster Toolbar" and comes by default with your QGIS installation (= no external plugin). To show it, go to "View --> Toolbars" and check "Raster Toolbar":

[image]